# how to write a query in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

i am writing a query  with inner join involved in it but having an doubt on how to write it using prepared statement here is my query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM detail INNER JOIN shortlisted ON detail.id = shortlisted.shortlisted_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//html part
}
```

also what should we pass in bind param if we have no particular condition to satisfy for our select query like

```
$query = "select * from details";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
   //$stmt->bind_param(); 
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($full_name);

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {

//html code
}
```

Comment: Both queries don't have input parameters so you don't need to bind any parameter.

Comment: meaning bindparam should not be written or the argument must be empty??